# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGSvgViewAndroid" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, expo-go

I am having a headache with the error mentioned in the title.
I am using react-native-gifted-charts (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-charts/v/1.0.3)
The charts works perfectly in ios but in Android it keeps crushing and throwing "Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGSvgViewAndroid" was not found in the UIManager."
First I thought it was a problem of my code as it worked for Android before,but even I reverse the code the error continues.
I am using using yarn as a pack manager and Expo Managed Workflow.
The dependencies are the following.

```
"react-native": "0.70.5",
"react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.2.42",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "2.6.2",
"react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
```

■Things I tried

1. I removed the node modules and ran yarn again ← didn't work
2. I changed the versions of react-native-svg as I read in the article below sometimes this kind of errors happens beacause of the missmatch of the versions.← didn't work
   https://github.com/Abhinandan-Kushwaha/react-native-gifted-charts/issues/263
3. I removed react-native-gifted-charts react-native-linear-gradient react-native-svg and yarn added again to see if it solves the problem. ← didn't work
4. At the end, to confirm my code is not the problem I deleted all the code and made a simple barChart example to see if it works (sample code below) ← didn't work

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import type { NativeStackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { MainStackParamList } from "../types/navigation";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { BarChart, LineChart, PieChart } from "react-native-gifted-charts";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../store";

export const StatisticsScreen: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const data=[ {value:50}, {value:80}, {value:90}, {value:70} ]
  return (
    <BarChart
      data={data}
    />
  );
};
```

P.S I also ran yarn cache clean hoping it was the cache but didn't help...

Comment: Note: `react-native-gifted-charts` includes native code that is not part of the Expo SDK and is therefore not built into Expo Go. When the JavaScript parts of Gifted Charts try to access the native code, they will fail because it is missing. You will need to create a [Development build](https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/) and use that instead of Expo Go.

Answer (score 50):

I also got the same problem when trying to use `react-native-heroicons` which required me to install `react-native-svg` but when I ran `npx expo install react-native-svg`, it worked.

Comment: This approach worked to me, thanks!

Comment: Also when running `expo start`, expo will notify you need to install specific version. Like this `Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
Install individual packages by running npx expo install react-native-svg@13.4.0`

Comment: Exactly! It worked by npx expo install react-native-svg, was throwing error by npm i

Comment: did not work for me, something might have recently changed /:

Comment: Are you guys still facing this issue? A new version of react-native-gifted-charts is recently released which has svg listed as a peer dependency instead of a direct dependency. Please try the latest version of the library where this issue is hopefully resolved.

Answer (score 15):

I got the error when I used `"react-native-svg": "13.6.0"`, downgrading to `"react-native-svg": "13.4.0"` solved the issue.

So maybe you can try to upgrade to the `13.4.0` version?

Comment: I had the same issue and changing version to 13.4.0 worked in development build, but the problem is that the expo doctor is throwing error that "react-native-svg" needs to be at 13.9.0. Any solution for this ?

Comment: @KazimHomayee, I don't think it's possible, expo-doctor doesn't seem to have any configurations. Also, it's been a year, and maybe react-native-svg version 13.13.0 doesn't have the issue, have you tried it?

Comment: just tried version 13.13.0, expo-doctor still saying it's not compatible and it needs 13.9.0 which doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Expo works with 13.4.0 version of `react-native-svg` but `react-native-gifted-charts` requires 13.6.0. So I installed `react-native-svg` with `expo install` and override nested dependencies to use 13.4.0 version also by adding

```
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0"
  }
```

to my package.json. Solved my issue

Comment: Yep, 13.6.0 is inop on Android.

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: @Nemanja Pavlović  Hey can you post your package json ? this isn't working for me

Comment: @ErickAdam It looked something like this:

`{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
   ...
    "expo": "^47.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.2.42",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    ...
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0"
  }
}`

Comment: @NemanjaPavlović  are you using expo dev client?

Comment: @ErickAdam Not really

Answer (score 2):

Expo uses `yarn` behind the scenes when using `npx expo install [dependency]`, which is a little awkward, considering their initialization script (i.e., `npx create-expo-app my-app`) installs the package dependencies using `npm`.

So if you use

```
npx expo install react-native-svg
```

to install the `react-native-svg` package, just be sure to remove your `package-lock.json` file, and run

```
yarn install
```

so you don't have multiple package managers in your project (it can cause havock for your dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

```
npx expo install react-native-svg
```

it's work for me with fontawesome 6 pro
i have react-native-svg version 13.6.0 but

```
npx expo install
```

fix it to version 13.4.0

Answer (score 0):

This happened because the latest library version internally uses

> "react-native-svg": "13.6.0"

check this [commit](https://github.com/Abhinandan-Kushwaha/react-native-gifted-charts/commit/d3fe2d490def2c95543b5dacd5cfea9b91079c13)

so even though we install a different version of

> "react-native-svg"

it uses version "13.6.0" which does not work in android at the moment. For me downgrading to

> "react-native-gifted-charts": "1.2.41"

worked.

Answer (score 0):

Install this version. npx expo install react-native-svg@13.4.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i using expo at my android device. running app with qr code.

i take the error ->

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGSvgViewAndroid" was not found in the UIManager
```

because i was `"react-native-svg": "13.6.0",`

if you want solve the error you need the downstrain

```
npx expo install react-native-svg@13.4.0`
```

please check package.json at here

https://github.com/berkaynayman/e-commerce-mobile-app

Comment: Which version of expo, and which version of react-native-gifted-charts are you using? Also, are you using Expo dev-client?

Comment: Hi Erick, i edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade Expo to the newest version - 49.0.21 (at least for me it worked)

Answer (score -1):

SVG rendering requires this module

```
npm install react-native-svg-transformer --save
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I ran the command you recommend and now the error message changed to "java.lang.Double cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap" which brings me to the very first error I had. I checked this ticket in Gihub hoping that matching the versions of react-native-svg and react-native-linear-gradient would solve the problem but it didn't....
https://github.com/Abhinandan-Kushwaha/react-native-gifted-charts/issues/263

Comment: You don't need this to use RN Gifted Charts